# Honda CRV 2000 loses power, sputters and putt putts while driving. it doesnt do this at idle

Tags: honda, troubleshooting

at first I thought maybe water in the tank so I let the gas get low then added gas de icer treatment in and half a tank of gas. it seemed to stop but then started intermittently. it idles ok but now it putt putts and loses power more often to the point i feel the car is going to conk out. my check engine light starts to flash when this happens now and Im afraid to drive it at this point because it i happenning so often now. would this be spark plugs or n other possible problem?

Comment: If the check engine light is illuminated there are one or more codes.  Get them read out.  That will likely point to the issue.  Many auto parts stores will read the codes for you free of charge.

Comment: Check for a clogged fuel filter.

Answer (score 0):

A flashing check engine light means there is damage taking place primarily to the catalytic converter. It should not be driven in this condition. When you have the codes read you more than likely are going to have codes P0300, P0301, P0302, P0303 or P0304. Retrieving these codes and what ever other ones will greatly assist a mechanic in pinpointing the problem and he can make the fix in short order. But if you are a do it yourself type person there are things you can do to "maybe" fix it yourself. First confirm that you have one of the P0300 codes listed above. If you do not know when the spark plugs have been changed last, or if it's been over 20,000 miles since they have been changed then it would not be a waste of money to replace them now because they are due anyways. This is the most common cause for these conditions. I believe this engine is coil over plug so diagnosing them is more involved, but if it has plug wires try replacing them also. If you are not a do it yourself type person, you should take it to a reputable shop to have it diagnosed and repaired soon.